# Any quantum state is an eigenstate of some complete observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, observables

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$

*Quantum Mechanics and Experience* by David Albert states (p. 63):

> $$\ket{A} = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ket{\text{black}}_1  \ket{\text{white}}_2 - \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ket{\text{white}}_1  \ket{\text{black}}_2$$
>
> $\ket{A}$, **like any quantum state, is necessarily an eigenstate of some complete observable of this state of electrons**.

Note that two-valued “colour” is just a metaphor for the spin state of some electron in some particular basis.

My question is, how can I understand the highlighted statement? It actually came as a bit of a surprise. I suppose it follows from some simple maths, though my QM maths is pretty rusty. Also, how should I understand it from a physical perspective? I am used to equating observables with measurable physical quantities, but how can an entangled state be observable/measurable in this sense?

Comment: I assume the intended meaning is that, right after a projective measurement is performed, a physical system is in an eigenstate of an observable.

Comment: @secavara He goes on to state $O_A \ket{A} = \ket{A}$ where $O_A$ is that observable, so it seems not hmm.

Comment: I am not sure of the intention of the author. In itself the statement is probably not wrong, in the sense that if your system is in the (normalized) state $|A\rangle$, then this is trivially an eigenstate of the projector $|A\rangle\langle A |$, which is hermitian.

Comment: What is a complete observable?

Comment: Finding a set of observables that together with that projector are complete may be the challenge. With a Hilbert space of finite dimension, this will always be possible. In the general case, what you may need is your Hilbert space and $|A \rangle \langle A|$ to fit the assumptions of some form of the spectral theorem.

Comment: @secavara Interesting. Is that not always the case? And can we not have a single complete observable?

Comment: Ah, I see this is possible per Valter’s answer...

Comment: @Noldorin I am just wondering what would happen in a sick infinite-dimensional case in which $|A\rangle \langle A|$ happens to be ill-defined in some way, perhaps with respect to its domain or *bounded-ness*. My hope is that some form of the spectral theorem will still hold but I can't tell for sure, as I am no expert in the field of those subtleties.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Isn’t the spectral theorem guaranteed from the axioms of QM though? I mean, if we have a Hermitian operator on a separable complex inner-product Hilbert space, does it not follow anyway, or do we definitely need boundedness? I honestly don’t know, as I haven’t properly studied the maths here.

Answer (score 5):

This is true only for pure states but given you have a ket (which is a pure state), the statement can be taken as true.

The point is: given a (normalized) ket $\vert \psi\rangle$, construct the operator $$
\hat {\cal O}=\vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi\vert + \vert \phi\rangle \langle \phi\vert
$$
where $\langle \psi\vert\phi\rangle=0$.  Clearly
$$
\hat {\cal O}\vert \psi\rangle= 
\vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi\vert \psi\rangle+ \vert \phi\rangle \langle \phi\vert \psi\rangle=
\vert \psi\rangle \tag{1}
$$
so $\vert \psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat {\cal O}$ with eigenvalue $+1$.

That's the basic result.  It needs to be augmented to account for possible degeneracies.  Suppose you have $\hat T$ so that $[\hat T,\hat{\cal O}]=0$, then $\vert \psi\rangle$ is either an eigenstate of $\hat T$ or a linear combination of eigenstates of $\hat T$ with the same eigenvalues.   You can in this way refine (1) until your $\vert \psi\rangle$ is actually an eigenstate of a set of commuting operator (possibly taking combos of eigenstates of $\hat T$ in the process).

It has to be a complete set else there could be another *different* state
$\vert \psi'\rangle$ for which $\hat{\cal O}$ etc would have the same eigenvalues (*i.e.* same outcomes), and you'd have no way of differentiating it from $\vert \psi\rangle$ given a set of outcomes of your commuting operators.

In your case,  using the shorthand notation
\begin{align}
\vert bb\rangle &= \vert \hbox{black}\rangle \vert \hbox{black} \rangle\, ,\\
\vert ww\rangle &= \vert \hbox{white}\rangle \vert \hbox{white} \rangle\, \\
\vert bw;\pm\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\vert \hbox{black}\rangle \vert \hbox{white} \rangle\pm 
\vert \hbox{white}\rangle \vert \hbox{black} \rangle \right)
\end{align}
your state is an eigenstate of
\begin{align}
\hat{\cal O}= \vert bb\rangle\langle bb\vert +  \vert ww\rangle\langle ww\vert +  \vert bw;+\rangle\langle bw;+\vert
+  \vert bw;-\rangle\langle bw;-\vert\, . \tag{2}
\end{align}
Clearly $\hat{\cal O}$ is not unique,  but your state *is* an eigenstate of
$\hat{\cal O}$, and that's all you need.

Note that there is nothing to suggest that $\hat{\cal O}$ needs to be realizable in practice: it could be a purely formal operator and it could be impossible to construct an apparatus to measure this operator, but formally it exists and that's good enough for the argument.

Comment: Thank you, that’s very helpful. Incidentally, I’m not sure if you have the book at hand or can view that page, but why is it even important that this operator is a complete observable? (It’s an explanation of the EPR argument.)

Comment: @Noldorin an operator by itself is not a complete observable.  A complete set of (commuting) observables is supposed to supply sufficiently many labels to unambiguously identify all the states of your system.

Comment: Sure, but why do we need such a condition for the EPR argument? Isn’tt it enough that the colour observable is a non-degenerate operator? Also, re a single observable, doesn’t @Valter Moretti show it!s possible in his answer? Sorry if I’m missing something obvious.

Comment: @Noldorin we must be talking at cross-purposes here.  I don’t see how EPR related to this.  A  “complete observable” might mean every eigenvalue is distinct, and that would be enough to completely label your states but one usually speaks of complete set of commuting observables.   See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables.  The eigenstates of a hermitian operator also form a complete set in the sense that any state has an expansion in terms of this set.

Comment: Well, the context of the quote of my original question within the book is to explain the EPR argument. I don’t especially see the relevance to the argument though!

Answer (score 2):

Here is  another answer. Suppose the space is finite-dimensional or countably infinite dimensional. We concentrate on the latter   case only since the former is a trivial subcase. Let $\{|n\rangle\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a Hilbert basis such that $|0\rangle = |A\rangle$.
Define the observable
$$H = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} n |n\rangle \langle n|\:.$$
This observable forms a complete observable without adding further observables, and
$H|A\rangle =0\:.$
As in the other answer, in general $H$ has no direct physical meaning.

The procedure can be extended to the case of an infinte dimensional space whose cardinality is the one of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that’s a really straightforward way to construct a single complete observable! If you have any idea about my follow-up question (see my comment on the other answer), do please let me know.